# My iPhone app with a bug got approved, is there a way to roll back to a previous version?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I know if I fix the bug I have to go through the approval process again.  Is there a way to rollback to a previous (approved) version?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without submitting another binary. :(

Comment: I concur. You can reject the app to pull it, but not roll back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an "Emergency" approval request for situations such as this.  I can't find a reference to this so I suggest you contact Apple or email: appreview@apple.com.  You can call the support number and ask.

This was announced in June or thereabouts.

Comment: Where is that? You mean email the approval team?

Comment: Yep. I've done it before and it led to my fix getting approved in about 3-4 days.